# how to make Items spawn when you combine two other items together

Tags: unity-game-engine

i am making a 2D game and i want to make users combine two Herbs from the collection to make a certain potion i have no idea how to achieve that though i'm stuck in this step after i made the scene and the spawning script. Any idea how to spawn Potions after i throw for example 2 Herbs combination in the pot to mix them and get a result that is a certain potion that i assign to them?

[image: Picture from the game i'm making]

Comment: How do you want to detect this so called "combining together"?

Comment: i want to pick them from an inventory for example then they go to the boiler and give a certain potion that i assign to them as a result. i know it sounds like an annoying idea but i don't know if it's possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay well, bear with me this is going to be a hefty one, I'll start by explaining a bit the thoughs that went into my solution, then you'll find my code as well as a demonstration of how it works.

I went for a "drag and drop" style, ingredients being represented as gameobject that can be dragged up to the cauldron.

When an ingredient touches the cauldron, it is added to it. To keep thinkgs simple I did this with colliders.

As for the making of the potion, the logic is separated into two classes :

- The PotionRecipe class will hold the combinaison of ingredients needed to make a potion as well as the Prefab that should be spawned when this recipe is crafted.
- The PotionCrafter class is in charge of making a potion out of the ingredients in the cauldron

Recipes can need different amount of the same ingredient, ingredients are lost if we try to make a potion when the ingredients in the cauldron don't match any recipe

For the sake of complexity and time, I made a static "repository" of handcrafted potion recipes that cannot be edited via the inspector, this solution is not viable for a big project but it help illustrate how does my solution work.

**Enough with all the talks, here's some code**

(To make the code easier to use, I removed all of my namespaces and put everything except for the MonoBehaviour in a big blob)

##### The Potion Brewing logic :

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using Object = UnityEngine.Object;

public enum Ingredient
{
    Garlic,
    Aloe,
    Lichen
}

public class PotionRecipe
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public uint NumberOfIngredients { get; }

    // A dictionary containing the quantity of
    // each ingredient needed to make this potion
    private Dictionary<Ingredient, uint> Recipe { get; }

    // The Potion GameObject can contain the prefab
    // corresponding to this potion and its components
    private readonly GameObject _potionPrefab;

    public PotionRecipe(string name, Dictionary<Ingredient, uint> recipe, GameObject potionPrefab = null)
    {
        Name = name;
        Recipe = recipe;
        NumberOfIngredients = (uint)Recipe.Values.Sum(u => u);
        _potionPrefab = potionPrefab;
    }

    // Check if the recipe is made with the given ingredient and if the amount of it is correct
    public bool IsMadeWith(Ingredient ingredient, uint quantity)
    {
        if (!Recipe.ContainsKey(ingredient)) return false;

        return Recipe[ingredient] == quantity;
    }

    public GameObject CreatePotion()
    {
        // Instantiate the potion prefab or create a new empty object for demonstration
        return _potionPrefab ? Object.Instantiate(_potionPrefab) : new GameObject(Name);
    }
}

public class PotionBrewer
{
    private readonly HashSet<PotionRecipe> _potionRecipes;

    public PotionBrewer()
    {
        // Get the list of recipes from the repository
        _potionRecipes = PotionRecipeRepository.Recipes;
    }

    public GameObject MakePotion(Queue<KeyValuePair<Ingredient, uint>> ingredients, uint numberOfIngredients)
    {
        if (ingredients.Count == 0) return null;

        // Only test recipes that have the same number of ingredients in them
        foreach (var recipe in _potionRecipes.Where(recipe => recipe.NumberOfIngredients == numberOfIngredients))
        {
            // Make a copy of the ingredient queue for each loop
            var ingredientsCopy = ingredients;

            Ingredient ingredient;
            uint quantity;

            // Iterate over the queue as long as the ingredients are matching
            do
            {
                // If the ingredient Queue is empty, we matched all the ingredients
                if (ingredientsCopy.Count == 0)
                {
                    // Return the potion associated with this recipe
                    return recipe.CreatePotion();
                }

                (ingredient, quantity) = ingredientsCopy.Dequeue();

            } while (recipe.IsMadeWith(ingredient, quantity));

        }

        // Otherwise we failed to make a potion out of this recipe
        return null;
    }
}

// This is a static repository made for this example
// It would be probably best to replace is by something configurable in the editor
static class PotionRecipeRepository
{
    public static HashSet<PotionRecipe> Recipes { get; } = new();

    static PotionRecipeRepository()
    {
        var healingPotion = new Dictionary<Ingredient, uint>()
        {
            [Ingredient.Garlic] = 2,
            [Ingredient.Aloe] = 1
        };

        Recipes.Add(new PotionRecipe("Healing Potion", healingPotion));

        var sicknessPotion = new Dictionary<Ingredient, uint>()
        {
            [Ingredient.Lichen] = 1,
            [Ingredient.Garlic] = 1
        };

        Recipes.Add(new PotionRecipe("Sickness Potion", sicknessPotion));
    }
}
```

##### The Cauldron.cs component :

To be attached to the cauldron GameObject, it uses a SphereCollider

```cs
public interface IBrewingCauldron
{
    public void AddIngredient(Ingredient ingredient);
    public GameObject BrewPotion();
}


[RequireComponent(typeof(SphereCollider))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class Cauldron : MonoBehaviour, IBrewingCauldron
{
    public Dictionary<Ingredient, uint> Ingredients { get; private set; } = new();

    [SerializeField] private SphereCollider cauldronCollider;
    private readonly PotionBrewer _potionBrewer = new();
    private uint _numberOfIngredients;

    private void Awake()
    {
        cauldronCollider ??= GetComponent<SphereCollider>();
        // Set the collider as trigger to interact with ingredients GameObject
        cauldronCollider.isTrigger = true;
    }


    public void AddIngredient(Ingredient ingredient)
    {
        // Keep track of the number of ingredients added
        _numberOfIngredients++;

        if (!Ingredients.ContainsKey(ingredient))
        {
            Ingredients[ingredient] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            Ingredients[ingredient]++ ;
        }
    }

    public GameObject BrewPotion()
    {
        var ingredientQueue = new Queue<KeyValuePair<Ingredient, uint>>(Ingredients);

        var potionObject = _potionBrewer.MakePotion(ingredientQueue, _numberOfIngredients);

        if (potionObject is not null)
        {
            Debug.Log($"We made a {potionObject.name} !");
            potionObject.transform.position = transform.position;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("We failed to make any potion !!!");
        }

        Ingredients = new Dictionary<Ingredient, uint>();
        _numberOfIngredients = 0;

        return potionObject;
    }
}
```

##### The PotionIngredient.cs component

To be attached to every ingredient GameObject, they need the Cauldron's GameObject to function, if they don't have it or if the GameObject doesn't contains the Cauldron's script, they will disable themselves.

```cs
public class PotionIngredient: MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject cauldronGameObject;

    [SerializeField] private Ingredient ingredient;

    private SphereCollider _cauldronCollider;

    private IBrewingCauldron _cauldron;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (cauldronGameObject is not null)
        {
            _cauldron = cauldronGameObject.GetComponent<IBrewingCauldron>();

            if (_cauldron is not null) return;
        }

        var ingredientObject = gameObject;
        ingredientObject.name += " [IN ERROR]";
        ingredientObject.SetActive(false);

        throw new MissingComponentException($"{ingredientObject.name} is missing the cauldron gameobject");
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        _cauldronCollider = cauldronGameObject.GetComponent<SphereCollider>();

        gameObject.name = ingredient.ToString();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other != _cauldronCollider) return;

        _cauldron.AddIngredient(ingredient);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

##### Finally, a small custom editor I made to test my code :

```cs
[CustomEditor(typeof(Cauldron))]
public class CauldronEditor : UnityEditor.Editor
{
    private Cauldron _cauldron;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _cauldron = (Cauldron) target;
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();


        EditorGUILayout.Space();
        var ingredients = _cauldron.Ingredients;

        if (ingredients.Any())
        {
            GUILayout.Label("Ingredients :");

            EditorGUILayout.Space();

            foreach (var (ingredient, quantity) in ingredients)
            {
                GUILayout.Label($"{ingredient} : {quantity}");
            }
        }

        EditorGUILayout.Space();
        if (GUILayout.Button("BrewPotion"))
        {
            _cauldron.BrewPotion();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a small gif illustrating how my solution is working inside the editor.

[image: Demonstration of the solution]

There's quite a bit of code so if you find yourself having troubling using it, I can also share a github link of a working project.

Hope this helps.

Comment: that is some brilliant Job man! this is too kind of you i appreciate it. i will try these codes and see. and i would be a bit annoying to ask you for the Github link for the whole code. you are amazing myfriend i can't thank you enough you saved my life as my game project should be delivered after this month to my teacher. thanks a bunch once again!

Comment: i'm kinda confused applying these codes even though they're kinda working so i'll be appreciated if you can share the github project so i can see how you did it. thank you so much

Comment: If it's your first time using Unity yes you might has some trouble figuring out everything, here's the github link : https://github.com/Delran/potion-craft
There's a lot I left unexplained so I can clarify some points if you point me towards them.

Comment: i'll try it out and let you know if i have something wrong thank you so very much!

Comment: I got this error when i tried to save the scripts and drag them to the items

Assets\Scripts\Cauldron.cs(50,57): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Queue<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<PotionCraft.PotionRecipe.Ingredient, uint>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Queue<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<Ingredient, uint>>'

Comment: In the Github project, the Ingredient enum belongs to the PotionRecipe Class, it is not located in the global namespace, the Ingredient enum probably exists twice in your code, get rid of the one you're not using and use the one you kept

Comment: so do i remove this line var ingredientQueue = new Queue<KeyValuePair<PotionRecipe.Ingredient, uint>>(Ingredients);  from the Cauldron's script because thats what unity is showing the error

Comment: The problem is that you have different version of my code, in the code I gave you on this site, the enum Ingredient can be acceced by typing "Ingredient" but in the Github project, the enum is located under the namespace PotionCraft.PotionRecipe.Ingredient as it is part of the PotionRecipe Class

Comment: You most likely copied parts of the github code while also keeping parts of the code I wrote on stack overflow, which will produce errors if you don't change the namespaces appropriately

Comment: it's just taht i don't know what to put in the namespace can I name it anything i want? or does it have to be something specific

Comment: If this is somethings like that `namespace PotionCraft { public class PotionRecipe { public enum Ingredient } }` the you access it typing PotionCraft.PotionRecipe.Ingredient

Comment: I managed to fix the problems but when i try to change the names of the items you have Garlic, Aloe... they don't change in the drop down menu when i want to pick the item's name. so i don't know and also when i put them in the Cauldron even with the sphere collider they don't show as items added to the cauldron. so when i press brew nothing happens and it says you failed to make any potions.

Comment: It's really hard to understand what is the problem, you're not being very clear. If you are changing the Items in the Ingredient enumeration but they don't change in the dropdown menu, it porbably mean that the enumeration is still present twice in your code and you're changing the one that you're not using.

Comment: But at this point ou should probably start posting more detailed question and the code you're using and sceenshots of what isn't working, I just can't help you this way.

Comment: i'll try to post stuff in a chat discussion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247062/discussion-between-kylorius-beno-and-a-delran).